# can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component issue with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

I'm trying to redirect my user to a private route. I'm using redux thunk to fetch user info from the database, with storeUser(), if the info exists then the user proceeds otherwise they get redirected back to the home page. However its not working as expected. Its redirecting back to the home page when It should be proceeding. I can do this using class based syntax and componentDidMount. I tried to counter this issue of no access to componentDidMount by using the authChecked state to determine when the component has finished rendering

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const [authChecked, handleAuthChecked] = useState(false);
    const [isAuth, handleIsAuth] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        props
            .storeUser()
            .then(() => {
                props.user.email ? handleIsAuth(true) : handleIsAuth(false);
                handleAuthChecked(true);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                handleAuthChecked(true);
            });
    }, [props]);

    if (authChecked) {
        return isAuth ? <props.component /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return null;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { storeUser })(PrivateRoute);
```

The code will always redirect the user though. isAuth will never return true even though props.user.email is true. It runs and redirects before it has chance to run handleIsAuth(true)

Comment: Each time your compoent renders it makes the StoreUser() async function call. You have to make sure it get called only once, by giving [] in the UseEffect's second argument .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues that may be causing the defects you see:

1. First issue is caused by function scope within `useEffect` and your callback for `storeUser`. Instead of relying on the callback to determine whether the user has an email address, just do that in your render condition and let redux + react render cycle help you out.
2. In addition, you should only call the `storeUser` action on mount. Not every time `props` updates.

For example:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const [authChecked, handleAuthChecked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        props
            .storeUser()
            .then(() => {
                handleAuthChecked(true);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                handleAuthChecked(true);
            });
    }, []);

    if (authChecked) {
        return !!props.user.email 
          ? <props.component /> 
          : <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    
    return null;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user,
    };
};
```